# trinidad 2 and myfaces 2.13

Tags: jsf, myfaces, trinidad

I have started a brand new web application, using myfaces 2.1.3, tomahawk 20-1.1.11 and trinidad 2.0.0. I followed the developers guide and got facelets, jsf and the tomahawk stuff to work. But the trinidad tags keep throwing this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.facelets.TrinidadFaceletViewHandler
```

I checked in the api and impl and there really is no TrinidadFaceletViewHandler. Is this an oversight, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have this in you web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.ALTERNATE_VIEW_HANDLER</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.facelets.TrinidadFaceletViewHandler</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Remove it!

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! And also putting the stuff in a form helps. Thanks for all the help guys. Time for some fun!!

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that you've somewhere a Facelets 1.x JAR file around in your `/WEB-INF/lib`. Remove it. It's already bundled in JSF 2.x libraries.

Ensure that you're reading the installation instructions for JSF 2.x and Trinidad 2.x, not JSF 1.x and Trinidad 1.x.

Comment: I cannot find a reference to any jsf 1.x jars, here is a listing of all the files in my webapps WEB-INF/lib folder:batik-awt-util-1.6-1.jar,batik-ext-1.6-1.jar, batik-gui-util-1.6-1.jar, batik-util-1.6-1.jar, commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar, commons-codec-1.3.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, commons-digester-1.8.jar, commons-el-1.0.jar, commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar, commons-io-1.3.2.jar, commons-lang-2.4.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, commons-validator-1.3.1.jar, myfaces-api-2.1.3-javadoc.jar, myfaces-api-2.1.3-jsdoc.jar, myfaces-bundle-2.1.3.jar, myfaces-impl-2.1.3-facelets-tlddoc.jar,7

Comment: myfaces-impl-2.1.3-javadoc.jar, myfaces-impl-2.1.3-tlddoc.jar, myfaces-impl-2.1.3.jar, myfaces-impl-shared-2.1.3-javadoc.jar, oro-2.0.8.jar, tomahawk20-1.1.11-javadoc.jar, tomahawk20-1.1.11-tlddoc.jar, tomahawk20-1.1.11.jar, trinidad-api-2.0.0.jar, trinidad-impl-2.0.0.jar, xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar,xmlParserAPIs-2.0.2.jar

Comment: I cannot find a instalation instruction set specific to trinidad 2.x. I could only find http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/installation.html

Comment: I have noticed some warning from tomcat when it starts up about the versions of some of the files, I have now removed the tld's and javadoc from the lib. But I still get that pesky ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't find any installation guide for JSF 2.x and Trinidad 2.x.

The documentation for Trinidad is really poor.